# Unexpected end of input Jquery

Tags: jquery, input, syntax-error

I'm getting this error, but I CHECKED ALL the brackets 20 times before posting. Can there be another problem? Thanks!!!

```
var ifBlock = function (options) {
    var options1 = options['entry']
    var options2 = options['condition']
    if (options1 != null && options2 != null) {
        return eval("VB.interpreter.dictionary["+options1+"]" + " " + options2)
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: The code inside your eval will generate invalid javascript. `VB.interpreter.dictionary[somevalue] someothervalue` Are you missing an `=`? You don't need eval for this.

Comment: The code given should work, given correct values for `options1` and `options2`.

Answer (score 1):

Run your whole code through http://jsbeautifier.org/ and check if you are missing some bracket in your overall script (which you probably are).